# Constrain a column across tables

Tags: postgresql, triggers, foreign-keys, constraints

I'm using Postgres to store formulae and elements of formulae across two tables. Basically, you have something like:

### Elements Table

| symbol | content |
| --- | --- |
| pi | 3.1.45 |
| lune | 42 |

### Formula Table

| symbol | content |
| --- | --- |
| area | pi*r^2 |
| rugsize | area*lune |

So, formulae can use elements but also other formulae in their content field. For this reason (and for general reduction of confusion) I would like to make symbol unique across both tables.

I can, of course, in the code that's doing the insertion, look up the entries before adding them and refuse to add a duplicate symbol. (I probably will do this, but I don't want the database reliant on that.) I could also require a tag within the formula table to specify when it's using another formula:

| symbol | content |
| --- | --- |
| rugsize | f(area)*lune |

I'm not crazy about that since it puts a burden on the user to remember that, or on the coder to secretly add and remove the "f()".

Everything I found on Stack and elsewhere went the other way: Forcing a column value to be present in another table, except for one suggestion that the unique items be kept in a separate table.

| symbol |
| --- |
| area |
| lune |
| pi |
| rugsize |

And then...actually, I'm still not sure how that would work at the DB level.

So, is there a way to do this with constraints or foreign keys, or must I write a trigger for each table to look into the other table?

Addition: I've simplified here greatly but the elements table is much more complex than I'm showing and has little in common with the formulae table.

Edited to add the above addition and to try to fix the one-column "symbol" table which looks fine in the editing preview but does not format correctly on the actual page.

Comment: Why not use a single table and have an attribute that specifies whether a symbol is just a simple constant or a formula?

Comment: I've over-simplified, I guess: The tables are not constants or formulae, but measurements and formulae, so they don't really have much in common.

Comment: Still, you could have a common table that contains the name and the type and references other tables, depending on the type. Then a unique constraint would do.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's how the last table could work. ID, then, table that uses that ID. Seems cumbersome but might be the only way to go.